# IE11: How to ALWAYS "Save As" with a location window?

Tags: internet-explorer-11, save-as

I am really tired of IE's stupidity and I simply can't figure out how to get it to do non-stupid things.  I am forced to use IE for certain things (FF is my goto browser) so the answer of "use a different browser" is non-applicable.

In FF, I have it set that when I click a download link it simply opens a windows explorer "save as" dialog immediately.  Its golden.

I tried the best I can to get IE to do this.  But I can't.  It always puts a tiny bar at the bottom with a dropdown selector for "save", "save as" and "open".  This bar always defaults to "save".  I want it to ALWAYS assume "save as" and go directly to the "where do you want to save it" dialog without the tiny bar (preferably)

I have tried the read-only folder as default location trick.  This woks ONCE.  The next time you click a file it assumes "save" goes to that last picked location and doesn't offer the ability to rename the file or pick another location again forcing me to use the dropdown and pick save as.

Honestly in 2018 this should not be a thing.  But apparently it is.

Anyone have a way to make IE immediately open the where-to-save dialog when clicking a download link?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to this is that there's no way to enforce this.
The long answer is as follows:

**Always Save As using Right Click and Save Target As:**
This option appears when you right click on an anchor tag (hyperlink) en press Save Target As. If the anchor tag's href attribute contains the direct URL to the file this will offer you the Save As window. This will not work with other elements when the href attribute is not used, but a small piece of javascript initiates the download.

**Always Save As using TrixIE:**
TrixIE is a plugin for Internet Explorer that allows you (amongst other things) to run Javascript. If you're good with Javascript you could create a plugin that will show a small download icon next to anchor tags and either initiate a download if the href attribute contains a direct URL to the file or try to resolve the small javascript that's behind the element. This will not always work and probably needs to be readjusted per site.

**Always Save As using a Browser Helper Object:**
Browser Helper Objects are DLLs that can be loaded into Internet Explorer. Plugins if you will. I'm not familiar with such plugins but I guess a plugin could be made to intercept a download request, present you with a Save As window and then handle downloading the file to the location you specified. I am not aware of existing plugins that do this, although I guess "Download Manager" plugins offer the same functionality.